# Azure Delete Causes 503 Service Not Available Exception

Tags: azure, http-status-code-503

I wrote a unit test that creates a container, adds a file, checks to see if the file exists, and then attempts to delete the file. When I get to the deletion step, I always get a 503 Service Unavailable though when I step through the unit test and look in the container, the file has been deleted (I have verified that it has been created as well). Any idea what I am doing wrong? I am using "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll" version 2.0.5.1 that I got from NuGet.

The same thing occurs when I try and delete the container.

Here is the the code I'm using. Seems pretty straight forward.

```
public void Save(string relativePath, Stream item)
{
    var cr = GetContainer(relativePath).GetBlockBlobReference(GetPath(relativePath));
    item.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    cr.UploadFromStream(item);
}

public void Delete(string relativePath)
{
    var cr = GetContainer(relativePath).GetBlockBlobReference(GetPath(relativePath));
    cr.DeleteIfExists();
}
```

Comment: We had this issue a few days ago, which turned out to be an Azure-side issue, and their support had to fix it. Has this suddenly happened?

Comment: In my case, this turned out to be related to our IT department's network monitoring solution blocking DELETE statements thinking that they were WebDav requests. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The OP wrote:

> In my case, this turned out to be related to our IT department's network monitoring solution blocking DELETE statements thinking that they were WebDav requests. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: ([Answered in the comments and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments?rq=1).)